# Limit axis range on pdp plot in python

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I want to generate a PDP plot for my data set in Python. I am using GradientBoostingClassifier along with a dataset.

The plots that I am getting has a different scale of Y-axis for every element. I want to set the limit of the range of Y-axis in between 0 and 1. How can I implement this in python. Below is the attached image.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Do following right before `plt.show()`:

```
plt.ylim(0, 1)
```

where `plt` is defined by `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt`.