# Trying to set a maximum value for my plot

Tags: python, matplotlib

How to set a maximum value for my partial dependance plot?  When I set the limit for the x axis it works, but it doesn't for the y axis, why?

Similar posts I looked at: [Limit axis range on pdp plot in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66964310/limit-axis-range-on-pdp-plot-in-python)

```
shap.partial_dependence_plot(
    "fc", model.predict, X100, ice=False, show=False,
    model_expected_value=True, feature_expected_value=True, ylabel="R")

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 

from matplotlib.pyplot import figure
#ax = plt.gca()
#ax.set_ylim([0, 600])

plt.rcParams["figure.dpi"] = 90
plt.xlim(0, 600)
plt.ylim(0, 600)

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`shap.dependence_plot`](https://shap-lrjball.readthedocs.io/en/latest/generated/shap.dependence_plot.html) seems to return a plot object but you store it no where, right ? If so, that's probably why you can't set the limit for the y-axis (since the plot isn't available yet!). I suggested you to do so :

```
fig, ax = shap.partial_dependence_plot(  # <- storing the plot in ax
    "fc", model.predict, X100, ice=False, show=False,
    model_expected_value=True, feature_expected_value=True, ylabel="R")

plt.rcParams["figure.dpi"] = 90
ax.set_xlim(0, 600) # <- changed plt by ax
ax.set_ylim(0, 600) # <- changed plt by ax

plt.show()
```

Comment: Thanks. I am getting an error: `AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'set_xlim'
`

Comment: Can you try to unpack the tuple like I did in the updated answer ? It should work for you now ;)